# How do I pass a uuid in an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, uuid

I'd like to pass a UUID identifying an object in an ArrayList to an intent, so that the recieving activity can find the object in the Arraylist using the id.

Is this possible, or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass `UUID.toString()` (as `String` in the `intent`). It returns the string representation of the `UUID` as specified in the `RFC 4122.` Anyway the UUID class implements the `Serializable` interface, so you can also pass it as object